# Web application much slower on IIS 7.5/8 than VS 2013 debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, iis

I deployed a web application to IIS, but the response time of specific actions are much slower than running in Visual Studio debugging mode.

I use it with an MS-SQL DB server. All configuration is the same. 
The published version generates ~7-8 sec TTFB times, the same action in VS debug is take about ~2sec.

I deployed to several environments(IIS 7.5, IIS 8.5) and tried out a lot of things. The Server resources are various, it should be more than enough.

What can be the problem?

Comment: One possible problem is that you are transmitting either lots of information or or a large number of requests. In VS Studio, you are presumably running client and server on the same machine. If your connection to the server is slow or high latency, the problem is exacerbated.

Comment: There are only one request, I integrated a stopwatch for that section and write the datas to an output file. The values are 0,5-1 sec for the program running. I deployed the application to my local machine and the problem is the same. The VS debug version of the application is much faster too on a global feeling.

Comment: Didn't you use a profiler?